# Angularjs bind to controller to execute function when changed

Tags: angularjs

Trying to use the new bindtocontroller for a directive however, struggling to find any working examples of how to execute a function when item changes.

Directive:-

```
.directive('freetextNote', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        activityRef: '@'
    },
    controller: 'TestCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'content/templates/test.html',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
};
```

and in the controller :-

```
$scope.$watch("activityRef",function(newValue,OldValue){
    debugger;
    if (newValue){
        //execute function
        alert(JSON.stringify(newValue)); 
    }
});
```

as i understand, there is no need to use "watch" when using bindtocontroller

Answer (score 0):

I don't use controllerAs and i don't always need to watchIt too. This is because every expression in the template are already "watched" by angular.

If this is only a displayed value you don't need to watch it. However if you need to perform some logic if the value change, you need a $watch or attr.$observe.

Comment: So basically dont use bindToController if i need to perform an action then the value changes..